# NetCore 1.1 + Npgsql, Add-Migration appears to ignore [NotMapped]?

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-migrations, npgsql, asp.net-core-1.1

Caveat: I'm very new to this, so go easy on me.
I'm developing an netcore application and am using Npgsql to connect to a postgresql database.  I'm not sure what is causing the error, but when I try to run Add-Migration with a model that has a 2-d array (double[][]) with the [NotMapped] attribute, I get the following error:

> System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type
>   'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.NpgsqlArrayTypeMapping'
>   to type
>   'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.NpgsqlBaseTypeMapping'.

I suspect it's not a Npgsql issue since, I would think, the [NotMapped] attribute should ignore the double[][] and not try to map it to something.

This is the offending part of the model

```
[NotMapped]
public double[][] LossData
{
    get
    {
       return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<double[][]>(InternalLossData);
    }
    set
    {
       InternalLossData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(value);
}
```

Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools is version 1.1.0-preview4-final.  I assume this is the package responsible for Add-Migration and therefore I suspect the problem may be there.

But I don't know.

**Update**

mww's suggestion didn't work so I switched over to using the default sql driver (not Npgsql) and it worked.  So that narrows it down to something I'm not doing correctly or something with Npgsql.

Comment: You want ignore this property?Are you try use `Fluent API`?

Comment: FYI, I strongly suspect this works simply because other EF Core drivers (e.g. SqlServer) simply don't support arrays at all, and therefore automatically ignore your property. I'll try to investigate this soon.

Comment: Issue: https://github.com/npgsql/Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL/issues/128

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for reporting, this was a bug in the Npgsql EF Core provider. The fix will be released for 1.1.1, in the meantime make your properly non-public (at least the getter or setter) or downgrade to 1.0.x.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Fluent API also, just add this in DBContext class to ignore property.

In method `OnModelCreating()` add

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
   modelBuilder.Entity<YourModelClass>().Ignore(d => d.LossData);
   base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
}
```

Comment: That change didn't seem to affect Add-Migration. I still get the same error message.  if I do "add-migration migration1 -verbose" I get a response like: Build started... Build succeeded... Setting app base path[...] Finding DbContext classes... Using context 'ApplicationDbContext' followed by the error message.  I added your code to the OnModelCreating of ApplicationDbContext right before base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder) as you have shown